# Add my own gstreamer plugins to totem player or mplayer

Tags: gstreamer, mplayer, totem

I want to add some of gstreamer plugins, which i have implemented, to totem player/mplayer so that it can use those plugins to play the given file.

please tell me  which player is having easy steps to add gstreamer plugins and please tell me how to add gstreamer plugins to that player.

Answer (score 0):

mplayer is not using gstreamer, you are out of luck there. For totem, you don't need to do anything special. If gst-inspect shows your plugin, totem can use them too. Can you give some examples about what kind of plugins you wrote (decoders for what formats or demuxers or protocol sources?)